# rtree/btree data structure go upper from child to parent

Tags: geospatial, knn, spatial-query, r-tree

I am new to rtree/btree data structures. The creation of the tree is a bottom-to-up process but searching for a node/range search/knn search are all top-to-bottom process. I am using knn search but wanting to do some improvement: my data are a trajectory of points, which are spatially close to each other. In order to search the KNNs for every point on the entire trajectory, I want to search one point first, then for other points, I don't want to start from the root again, instead I want to start from the results of the first point, and go upper to their parents. This will enable me to avoid searching a lot of unnecessary pages. The problem here is how can i go upper from the child to its parent in a rtree/btree structure? Should I change the tree creation process and whenever the split happens, fill the parent[] property of the child? Is there any other simpler ways for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Store a pointer to parent node in children node to know how to move upwards in the nodes structure. So between queries store some pointer to the last leaf node and from there using the pointer to parent move upwards, check the parent node, then again move upwards etc. until a node where a different subtree should be picked.
2. Store only pointers to children nodes in every node. Then between queries save the whole path of nodes used to get from the root to a leaf in the last query. Then having a last path you could go backwards in this collection which would represent going upwards from the leaf used in the last query to a node where you should pick a different subtree.